# Use History.js to save shown igGrid columns

Tags: javascript, history.js, ignite-ui, iggrid

is there any way to save chosen columns in history.js and/or diplay it in url?

Working solution for sorting is here: http://www.igniteui.com/grid/history/?sort=goals_descending;assists_descending (on asc/dsc registering changes in url),

and I want to do the same when filtering columns to be Shown/Hidden, if it is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please follow [this thread](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/106559/502798.aspx#502798) in the Infragistics forum.